# Redirect/Block outgoing HTTP traffic for a specific URL in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, proxy, http

On my Ubuntu server I have some custom software running, that connects to its vendor server to search for updates. While this is useful in general, the software is not supposed to update itself for security reasons.
I found out that, if there's no internet connection, the software is unable to update, but will still start. But I obviously can't close the connection. The `hosts` file is not an alternative either, as the software needs to connect to the vendor for license checks.

So my question is: How can I redirct or block outgoing HTTP traffic for a specific URL.

**tl;dr:** `http://www.vendor.com/license` should be allowed, but `http://www.vendor.com/update` should be blocked for outgoing traffic.

Comment: I know, that I can put up some custom proxy, but I want to be the most efficient as possible and looking for other possibilities.

Maybe iptables is what I'm looking for?

Comment: nope. Definitely not IPtables unless you want to compile with additional module that perform analysis on a top layer of OSI/ISO. I guess the easiest would be a setting on a router - some security policy. I think Linksys routers have such option. Linksys WAG320n has such option: http://i.imgur.com/3d6UmEw.jpg

Comment: additionally - if the software updates itself I think there might be a config setting that says to do it. Maybe you are able to change the config ?

Comment: `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "URL_HERE" --algo kmp -j DROP` Great thing that HTTP Headers are sent in cleartext. :D

Comment: Hm... `wget URL_HERE` now goes on forever... Is there a way to actually close the connection instead of only dropping it?

Comment: Try REJECT instead of DROP.

Comment: Doesn't work either... `wget` says "HTTP request sent, awaiting response..."

Comment: Right, the problem is that you're "rejecting" the connection after it has already been established. Use `-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`. This will alert the application that the connection has been reset.

Comment: You rock! It works. :)

Answer (score 3):

Good thing, that HTTP and its headers are sent in cleartext! We can search for the URL in the HTTP Header with the `-m string` filter.

#### Example

We want to block: `http://www.example.com/I/am/some/distinguishable/URL`

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/I/am/some/distinguishable/URL" --algo kmp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Thanks to [Dennis](https://superuser.com/questions/575912/redirect-block-outgoing-http-traffic-for-a-specific-url-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment703971_575912) for his tip on `--reject-with tcp-reset`.

Comment: it also stopped your own access to your own server  . He wants to limit outgoing, I guess.

Comment: This works for http, but I assume it won’t work for https right? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117536/is-https-url-in-plain-text-at-first-connection